# Display different styles on alternate rows of table (within a loop)

Tags: css, mysql, loops, html-table

I am populating a table with query results and I want the style of the rows to alternate i.e `<tr>` or `<tr class="alt>`. (Not using CSS3)

I using a while loop for displaying a row in my table for every result in the resultset.

How do I do this? I am lost.

Help please.

My solution:

```
   if($i % 2) { //this means if there is a remainder
     echo "<tr class='alt'>";
   } else { //if there isn't a remainder we will do the else
     echo "<tr>";
   }

$i++;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regular `for i` loop, you'd use `modulus` (which is the `%` operator) on `i` to see if it's a multiple of 2.

In a while loop, you'll need to use another sort of incrementer, perhaps just declaring one before you loop and incrementing it each pass though:

```
$i = 0;
while (condition) {
    $class = (i%2 == 0) ? 'alt' : '';
    echo '<tr class="' + $class + '">';
    $i++;
}
```

**Caveat:** I don't write much PHP, please treat the above as pseudo code. It should be pretty close to working though, if not straight-away correct.

Comment: Right, depends on who might maintain the code in the future (many don't get bitwise) and how long your tables might be/how loaded your site might be. I see it as a readability/performance trade, but it depends on how comfortable the OP is with bitwise vs. modulus. If both are Greek to him/her, $i & 1 might be just as good.

Comment: True, true, although I wouldn't  be surprised if `$i % 2` is silently optimised in the PHP core to `$i & 1`, which would make my argument moot :)